# How do you install a .MO (language file) to use as part of a theme?

Tags: themes, multi-language

I have my own theme that I've created and I need to support 3 languages. I started by adding the gettext functions to my template _e("string","namespace") etc, generated the po file with Poedit, and then created the .mo file for Spanish (es_ES)

My current setup which is not working >
**Update**

**wp-config.php**

```
define ('WPLANG', 'es_ES');
```

**functions.php**

```
define('TPL_LANGUAGES',TEMPLATEPATH.'/languages/');

function theme_init(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'protoman', TPL_LANGUAGES);
}

add_action('init', 'theme_init');
```

**languages mo file**

```
themes/protoman/languages/es_ES.mo
```

**index.php**

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php _e('Home', 'protoman'); ?> </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><?php _e('Account', 'protoman'); ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><?php _e('Shop', 'protoman'); ?> </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><?php _e('Corporate', 'protoman'); ?> </a></li>
```

STILL NO LUCK!

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Im using the WPML plugin and I actually have to set the language in the plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [load_theme_textdomain()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain) in your theme.

Place this in theme functions file:

```
function theme_init(){
    load_theme_textdomain('theme_name', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
add_action ('init', 'theme_init');
```

Then you put you language files in you theme /languages folder

you language files should be es_ES.mo and es_ES.po without the text domain at the front as the codex states `File names such as: my_theme-sv_SE.mo will NOT work.`

Comment: Yeah I did all that =/ still not working...

Comment: Ive edited my answer please re-read. This should clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that approach too, and updated my question with my current setup. Is there something missing perhaps in the .mo file? Like some setting I need to set in poedit?

Comment: The .po file must be created with proper path options. [Look at step 3 here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788930/wordpress-i18n-generator-missing-keys/13789150#13789150)

Comment: Also, you wont have to init this `load_theme_textdomain` in the `init` action. Just call this function on your functions.php thats all.